# How Group By works with Duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get some insight as to how some SQL statements work. Right know I am looking into `GROUP BY` and want to know, how does it choose what to show/return with duplicate data.

Consider the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE customers 
( 
    FirstName  VARCHAR(50), 
    LastName   VARCHAR(50), 
    MobileNo   VARCHAR(15) 
); 

INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('Niraj','Yadav',989898); 
INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('Chetan','Gadodia',959595); 
INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('Chetan','Gadodia',959590); 
INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('Atul','Kokam',42424242); 
INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('Atul','Kokam',42424246); 
INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('Vishal','Parte',9394452); 
INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('Vishal','Parte',939445); 
INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('Vishal','Parte',9394451); 
INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('Jinendra','Jain',12121); 
INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('Jinendra','Jain',121212);
```

If I run this query...

```
SELECT    *
FROM      customers
GROUP BY  FirstName;
```

I get the following results:

```
FirstName  LastName  MobileNo  
---------  --------  ----------
Atul       Kokam     42424242  
Chetan     Gadodia   959595    
Jinendra   Jain      12121     
Niraj      Yadav     989898    
Vishal     Parte     9394452
```

So, my question is: is there any reason why it returns these particular records? How does it determine what to get?  I'm using MySQL.

Comment: you shouldn't use GROUP BY if you don't have AGGREGATE functions in the SELECT statement

Comment: It is Order by dependent. And usualy it returns last row. Btw ANSI Sql will not allow select * with group by.

Comment: @bksi While that is what mysql appears to do, as pointed out by sstan's answer the values are documented as indeterminte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In other databases, your query would not be allowed exactly because the results are unpredictable in this case.

Notice what the MySQL documentation has to say for this case:

[MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html)

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are ***indeterminate***.

---

I should also mention, that Gordon Linoff recently pointed out to me that, starting in version 5.7 of MySQL, a query like yours, where unpredictable results are possible, will no longer be allowed by default.

Info on that: [MySQL 5.7: only_full_group_by Improved, Recognizing Functional Dependencies, Enabled by Default!](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-only_full_group_by-improved-recognizing-functional-dependencies-enabled-by-default/)

Comment: Thanks! So in Oracle or MS SQL this query would not execute?

Comment: In Oracle or MS SQL, you can only select columns that are part of the `GROUP BY`, or aggregate functions on any column.

Comment: You asked "Oracle or MS SQL this query would not execute?". Correct, it would not execute.